# getting the error "Mysql2::Error: Incorrect time value: '---" while saving the record in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, datetime

i am having the table punch_in_outs. and in corresponding model iam having the following code.

```
class PunchInOut < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :employee
    serialize :check_in, Array
    serialize :check_out, Array
end
```

and in migration i am having the following code

```
class ChangePunchInOutFields < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :punch_in_outs, :date,  :date
    change_column :punch_in_outs, :check_in,  :time
    change_column :punch_in_outs, :check_out,  :time 
  end
end
```

when i try to create the record   iam getting the error `Mysql2::Error: Incorrect time value: '---`

```
2.2.2 :001 > reload!
Reloading...
 => true 
2.2.2 :002 > p = PunchInOut.new
 => #<PunchInOut id: nil, employee_id: nil, check_in: [], check_out: [], date: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, shift_id: nil, shift_name: nil> 
2.2.2 :003 > p.check_in << Time.now
 => [2015-09-18 17:45:39 +0530] 
2.2.2 :004 > p.save
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (2.2ms)  INSERT INTO `punch_in_outs` (`check_in`, `check_out`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('---\n- 2015-09-18 17:45:39.760533268 +05:30\n', '--- []\n', '2015-09-18 12:15:44', '2015-09-18 12:15:44')
Mysql2::Error: Incorrect time value: '---
- 2015-09-18 17:45:39.760533268 +05:30
' for column 'check_in' at row 1: INSERT INTO `punch_in_outs` (`check_in`, `check_out`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('---\n- 2015-09-18 17:45:39.760533268 +05:30\n', '--- []\n', '2015-09-18 12:15:44', '2015-09-18 12:15:44')
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Incorrect time value: '---
- 2015-09-18 17:45:39.760533268 +05:30
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

What is a correct [mysql datetime literal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html): '2012-12-31 11:30:45'.

I believe that your literal was "2015-09-18 17:45:39.760533268 +05:30".
For more info on correct mysql datetime formats check the link. Good luck!

Comment: To format the time, you can use the following:

    Time.now.to_s(:db)

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your `check_in` and `check_out` attributes using [`serialize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize). This means that active record converts them to a YAML representation and tries to store that YAML representation as a string.

When it tries to store the YAML serialization in a mysql time field mysql responds with the error you're getting because mysql simply *can't* store a YAML string in a time column.

To store an array of time objects you're going to need `check_in` and `check_out` to be string columns in the database (maybe even text columns if you're going to store big arrays of times).

(You may also need to consider, if you just want to store a time in hours, minutes and seconds that `Time.now` returns a date/time with the full date in. This will be serialized with the day/month/year not just the hours/minutes/seconds.)

Answer (score 0):

See corresponding answer of the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32654104/384417

You can't serialize and store in a time column at the same time. Serialization gives rise to a TEXT (actually, encoded in YAML format), the database doesn't know it's a date or whatever.

In TIME/TIMESTAMP/DATE columns you can only store **single** values.