# unable to save Time object into the array of column Time, in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays

i having the array of datatype `Time`. when i try to insert the data in the following way iam getting the error.

```
2.2.2 :001 > p = PunchInOut.new
 => #<PunchInOut id: nil, employee_id: nil, check_in: [], check_out: [], date: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, shift_id: nil, shift_name: nil> 
2.2.2 :002 > p.check_in << Time.now
 => [2015-09-18 19:25:11 +0530] 
2.2.2 :003 > p.save
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO `punch_in_outs` (`check_in`, `check_out`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('---\n- 2015-09-18 19:25:11.695612520 +05:30\n', '--- []\n', '2015-09-18 13:55:19', '2015-09-18 13:55:19')
Mysql2::Error: Incorrect time value: '---
- 2015-09-18 19:25:11.695612520 +05:30
' for column 'check_in' at row 1: INSERT INTO `punch_in_outs` (`check_in`, `check_out`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('---\n- 2015-09-18 19:25:11.695612520 +05:30\n', '--- []\n', '2015-09-18 13:55:19', '2015-09-18 13:55:19')
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Incorrect time value: '---
- 2015-09-18 19:25:11.695612520 +05:30
' for column 'check_in' at row 1: INSERT INTO `punch_in_outs` (`check_in`, `check_out`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('---\n- 2015-09-18 19:25:11.695612520 +05:30\n', '--- []\n', '2015-09-18 13:55:19', '2015-09-18 13:55:19')
```

iam using mysql database. and also serialised these columns in the modal also. still iam getting the error

this is the code iam having in the model.

```
class PunchInOut < ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :check_in, Array
    serialize :check_out, Array
end
```

please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can't store in MySQL a serialized array in a TIME column, it needs be VARCHAR or TEXT.

When you serialize a field in ActiveRecord it is converted to a YAML text, so it's not compatible with a non-text column type.

You should store only single times in Time and Timestamp columns etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your `serialize` methods need `string` or `text` type column

```
add_column :push_in_outs, :check_in, :string
add_column :push_in_outs, :check_out, :string
```

And Rails serialize back these strings to `Time` format